# Black streaks on Minecraft rig model

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders

This is my first time animating minecraft and I haven't found a tutorial anywhere that solves this problem. These black streaks occur when I make the final render.

[image]

I've tried fixing the lighting but it seems to be a problem on the rig. The rig I am using is Neokat Rig 2.8. I have no experience to models so here is the .blend file.
https://www.mediafire.com/file/ffsbquhqv32xn7g/LobbyBackup.blend/file

Comment: Maybe overlapping faces? But you have not packed your images so we can't see the result. Also you don't have to share all the other objects, just share the character